# "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mean-stack

This is my employee.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService?.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter full name"
      required>
    <label>Name :
      <label class="red-text">*</label>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below one is the employee.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../shared/employee.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css'],
  providers: [EmployeeService]
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form) {
      form.reset();
      this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
        name: '',
        position: '',
        office: '',
        salary: null
      };
    }
  }

}
```

Chrome throw ***"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"*** error while loading my angular initial load.

Comment: change `if (form)` to `if (true)` and see if the error gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `Safe Navigation Operator ( ?. )` becouse of `employeeService?.selectedEmployee`  undefined

**[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/chrome-error-on-page-loading-error-typeerror-cannot-read-proper?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService?.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter full name" required>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@ViewChild('myForm') myForm:any;
  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm(this.myForm);
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form) {
      form.reset();
      this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
        name: '',
        position: '',
        office: '',
        salary: null
      };
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, but doesn't allow it and throws error => **Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 40 in [employeeService?.selectedEmployee?._id=$event] in @10:61**

Comment: StackBlitz demo also not working... i have attached the ss below here in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined”

Means that some reference to name is wrong. There is only one in your code : `employeeService?.selectedEmployee.name`, therefore `employeeService?.selectedEmployee` is `undefined`.

## Fix

Make sure `selectedEmployee` is not undefined, or use safe navigation `employeeService?.selectedEmployee?.name`

Comment: I tried this, but it throws error initially => **Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 40 in [employeeService?.selectedEmployee?._id=$event] in @10:61**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService?.selectedEmployee?.name" placeholder="Enter full name" required>
```

Add another  `?` after the **selectedEmplyee**. It will solve the problem.

The reason for the error is when the application starts the `selectedEmplyee` in `employeeService` is undefined. So make sure that variable is not **undefined**.

Comment: I tried this, but it throws error initially => **Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 40 in [employeeService?.selectedEmployee?._id=$event] in @10:61**

Answer (score 0):

you need to instantiate the employeeService.selectedEmployee object so it won't be undefined instantiate the object in the constructor or ngOnInit() and you can not use Safe Navigation Operator ( ?. ) in ngModel

eg:

```
 ngOnInit(){
this.employeeService.selectedEmployee=new Employee ();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna Rathore
[Screenshot of StackBlitz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTHZ5.png)